# How To Delete Rows In Gridview

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to delete multiple rows from a GridView but I am struggling to find Solution .
At the moment my code isn't attempting to delete anything.

.Aspx

Comment: please  give me solution what should i do

Comment: add some code and did you even try searching ?  `GridView1.DeleteRow(i);`

Comment: Don't delete rows from the GridView, but from the source data.

Answer (score 1):

> You can refer the following approach to delete multiple rows from grid
>   view.
>
> http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/delete-multiple-records-in-Asp-Net-gridview-using-check-box/
>
> https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Delete-multiple-rows-in-GridView-with-CheckBox-selection-and-with-confirmation-in-ASPNet.aspx
>
> https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/405576/Deleting-Multiple-Rows-in-GridView-in-ASP-NET